# Querying Chinese characters in Hive results none

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, hive, hiveql

### Problem:

I have a hive table that consists of 1 particular column that contains Chinese characters. For e.g `维 诶 吾`

And When I try to run the following query it does not return a single row.

```
Select * from db1 where col4 rlike "吾";
```

### Details:

Also just to check I have also tried Altering the table properties using `SERDEPROPERTIES("serialization.encoding"='UTF-8');` but without any luck.

I have also tried using the below query where **U+543E** represents the unicode value for `吾` :

```
Select * from db1 where col4 rlike "U+543E";
```

Does the above query require escape-sequencing or is it potentially an encoding issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the below worked for me:

```
Select * from db1 where long_text_field_2 rlike "\u8FCE";
```